# How to make my android app appears first in google play search?

Tags: android, google-play

I have published a new app to google play couple of hours ago, it is accessible through the app url, however I can’t find it by searching its name on google play search.
I have read some opinions saying it could take up to one week until it is indexed and appears in the search.

I am a bit concerned as the app name is a common name, so I would like to ask couple of questions:

1- In the country availability options in google play, I’ve selected to be in all countries, while in fact I am targeting just one country in the beginning. If I changed it to just one country, can this help my app to appear on the top if the search list for users in this country?

2- I understood there is a google play promotion to make the app appear first in the search, but can’t find from where exactly I can do this promotion.

3- Generally, how google play index the search results for users in a country.
Lets say there are two apps with the same name, one targeting specific country and one selected all countries. Which one appears first? Is it based on country availability? App downloads? Reviews?

Thanks